# Test Wake-On-LAN without actually doing it?

Tags: windows-10, power, remote, wake-on-lan

I have a bizarre request. I seriously need to verify whether or not a PC is able to be powered on via WOL, meaning that the BIOS and power settings on the PC are set up correctly and it would boot up when it receives the magig packet. However, I cannot actually shut this PC down and test it, it absolutely has to stay running. WOL is only if there is some emergency and it has to start back up. Is there any software or any way to find out if it would (!) power up after sending the WOL?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to examine the WOL packet as it comes into the computer to verify it's receiving the correct information. Unfortunately though I don't know of any way to verify the signal actually works without doing a live test. Even the Enterprise Server gear I've used require a full power off to test it.

Answer (score 1):

To test you can use this tool:

https://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-monitor

Also you need another machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to test it. Even if you use a test to verify that the WoL package arrived at the computer, many settings may make WoL not work, so it really does need a field test.

If the pc is so critical that the downtime cannot even be scheduled, you need to seriously ask yourself if you might need to change this, because if the pc would get a BSoD and thus crash, it sounds like that is going to be a catastrophe.

So... long story short, how to test this: Inform anyone that you will schedule a power-off to test this, and actually test it. Before the final test, you can use [WireShark](https://wireshark.com) to ensure that you can send the WoL package.

Also, keep in mind that you may not need a WoL construction. If all you want to do is verify that the pc is always up, you probably are already set by setting "auto power on after power failure" in the BIOS.